# Pass Vue 3 computed value to Pinia state to be used in cartStore

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

My ecommerce project has a Pinia `productStore` and `cartStore`.  My product does not have a default price--the price is computed based on user selected width, length and height constants as `calculatedPrice`.  Currently the product price is hard coded for testing, but I can't seem to figure out how to push the value of `calculatedPrice` as a state object to be used in my `cartStore`.  I am very new to Vue and Pinia--I hope this makes sense.  If not, I did a Loom cast here for reference https://www.loom.com/share/acdf711203d24792906be8c30a541fd2

**Products/Show.vue**

```html
<template>
...
<div class="grid grid-cols-4 gap-4">
 <div class="mt-4 sm:mt-0 sm:pr-9">
    <select v-model="width" id="width" name="width">
        <option value="3">3"</option>
        <option value="4">4"</option>
        <option value="5">5"</option>
    </select>
 </div>

 <div class="mt-4 sm:mt-0 sm:pr-9">
    <label for="height" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Outer
        Height:</label>
    <select v-model="height" id="height" name="height">
        <option value="3">3"</option>
        <option value="4">4"</option>
        <option value="5">5"</option>
    </select>
 </div>

 <div class="mt-4 sm:mt-0 sm:pr-9">
    <select v-model="length" id="length" name="length">
        <option value="10">10'</option>
        <option value="11">11'</option>
        <option value="12">12'</option>
    </select>
 </div>
</div>
<button @click="cartStore.add(product.id)">
    Add to Cart
</button>
...
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed, ref, reactive } from 'vue';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
import { useCartStore } from '../../store/cart';
import { useProductStore } from '../../store/products';
import type { Product } from '../../store/products';
import { toCurrency } from '../../shared/utils';

import CartCardSkeleton from '../../components/CartCardSkeleton.vue';

const cartStore = useCartStore();
const productStore = useProductStore();

const route = useRoute();

const height = ref('4')
const width = ref('4')
const length = ref('10')

const calculatedPrice = computed(() => {
    return ((((parseInt(width.value) + (parseInt(height.value) * 2)) * 12) / 144) * 25) * parseInt(length.value);
});

const product = computed<Product>(
    () => productStore.items[route.params.productId as string],
);
</script>
```

**store/product.ts**

```ts
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

const fakeStoreUrl = 'https://fakestoreapi.com';

export interface Product {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    category: string;
    featured_image: string;
    slug: string;
    sku: string;
}

interface ProductState {
    items: Record<string, Product>;
    ids: number[];
}

export const useProductStore = defineStore({
    id: 'products',

    state: (): ProductState => ({
        items: {},
        ids: [],
    }),

    getters: {
        list(): Product[] {
            return this.ids.map((i) => this.items[i]);
        },

        loaded(): boolean {
            return this.ids.length > 0;
        },
    },

    actions: {
        async fetchAll() {
            if (this.loaded) return;

            const res = await fetch(`/api/products`);
            const data: Product[] = await res.json();
            this.ids = data.map((product) => {
                this.items[product.id] = product;
                return product.id;
            });
        },
    },
});
```

**store/cart.ts**

```ts
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { CART_STORAGE } from '../composables/usePersistCart';
import { useProductStore } from './products';

export interface Purchase {
    productId: number;
    quantity: number;
    price: number;
}

interface CartState {
    contents: Record<string, Purchase>;
}

export interface CartPreview {
    id: number;
    featured_image: string;
    name: string;
    quantity: number;
    cost: number;
}

export const useCartStore = defineStore({
    id: 'cart',

    state: (): CartState => ({
        contents: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(CART_STORAGE) as string) ?? {},
    }),

    getters: {
        count(): number {
            return Object.keys(this.contents).reduce((acc, id) => {
                return acc + this.contents[id].quantity;
            }, 0);
        },

        total(): number {
            //const products = useProductStore();
            return Object.keys(this.contents).reduce((acc, id) => {
                /*return acc + products.items[id].price * this.contents[id].quantity;*/
                return acc + this.contents[id].price * this.contents[id].quantity;
            }, 0);
        },

        formattedCart(): CartPreview[] {
            const products = useProductStore();

            if (!products.loaded) return [];

            return Object.keys(this.contents).map((productId) => {
                const purchase = this.contents[productId];
                return {
                    id: purchase.productId,
                    featured_image: products.items[purchase.productId].featured_image,
                    name: products.items[purchase.productId].name,
                    quantity: purchase.quantity,
                    cost: purchase.quantity * purchase.price,
                    /*cost: purchase.quantity * products.items[purchase.productId].price,*/
                };
            });
        },
    },

    actions: {
        add(productId: number) {
            const p = 250
            if (this.contents[productId]) {
                this.contents[productId].quantity += 1;
            } else {
                this.contents[productId] = {
                    productId,
                    price: p,
                    quantity: 1,
                };
            }
            console.log(this.$state)
        },
        remove(productId: number) {
            if (!this.contents[productId]) {
                return;
            }

            this.contents[productId].quantity -= 1;

            if (this.contents[productId].quantity === 0) {
                delete this.contents[productId];
            }
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: Why not simply add a variable to your store that would be the calculated price, so you would have the list of your purchases with a unique price created with your computed function ` calculatedPrice` ?

Comment: Looks like you need either add price data to a card together with productId, or keep product data in another global store and and use it for calculations. Probably both, because it's not a bad idea to show that price was changed since a product was added to a cart

Comment: @EstusFlask My code above is from another project I found online--I wish I knew enough to write it myself.  Can you show me some code examples of what you suggest to help me piece it together?

Comment: @CharlesSmith Pass the calculated price as an argument in addition to the productId in the cartStore.add() function (or pass an object with productId and price instead of only a productId).